# Authenticity of password prompts

Tags: macos, security, password

[This article on osxdaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/04/fix-mac-asking-icloud-password-randomly/) discusses an issue in Mavericks and Yosemite where the user is prompted for passwords "at random times".

In the article, the following is claimed.

> [The scenario where an attacker prompts you for your password] may be very unlikely, but it’s just good practice to not trust random password prompts, regardless of where they come from.

I think this claim makes a lot of sense, even if it perhaps glosses over details. To me it seems strange that the timing of a prompt should matter: If you are doing icloud stuff and you are prompted for a password you may think this ok, but if prompted at a "random time" you may become suspicious. I think this is a good mindset from a practical point of view, but I think this does probably not correspond to the security model that the developers had in mind.

My hypothesis is that no application should be able to generate a prompt with an "official icon" in the top left area, like the lock, or the icon for icloud.

[image: lock]
[image]

I am not too worried about verifying the authenticity of a prompt from a browser (which is mentioned in the article), as I feel confident that I recognise such prompts. Any icon can be embedded in a website, but one can find out that the icon/prompt is then part of the website. My main concern is an attacker that already has access to your computer, but not administrator privileges.

My question is: Is there any practical way for a user to know that a password prompt is authentic? Should one rely on these icons?

**Related**

This [Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/902869) on superuser asks for methods to verify the validity of any window in a programmatic way, but I am looking for something more practical.

[ICloud Password prompt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/230748/176910) (possible duplicate)

Comment: The other is not a duplicate just asking in one case - this is more general

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password prompt diologue box](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210357/password-prompt-diologue-box)

Comment: @MaxRied Your answer in the Q&A you link to is interesting. Should I interpret this as a definite "no" to my question of whether we can trust these icons?

Comment: @MaxRied I would also be interested to know if you know if there exists a "secure attention key" for mac (since you asked a question about this (which can be found by following two links from here))

Comment: You can't rely on an image as a definitve indication. There is no sak as far as I know.

Comment: The other duplicate is not a duplicate as that is about the admin box (a different dialog) and also in the process of doing a task when you **expect** a dialog